# MS Word Shortcut Key for preformatted text

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the keyboard shortcut in MS Word to mark the selection with mono-spaced font a.k.a pre-formatted text ? Is there one else how would I configure one ?

Answer (score 1):

As Moshe Katz already mentioned;

1. first you need to create a custom Style for the font in question.
2. Then you can assign a custom keybord shortcut to this newly created Style.

A very **easy** and ***intuitive*** way of *creating custom shortcuts* in MS Office Word using the "loop squared symbol" technique is shown in the blog post [MVP-blog](http://mswordtipsandtricks.blogspot.co.at/2017/01/easiest-way-to-customize-keyboard.html).

---

Look at the second video in the blogpost for a clear demonstration of the technique.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built into Word to do exactly what you want, but you can set it up yourself pretty easily.

First, you need to create a Style that has the formatting you want. The easiest way to do that is to create a new style that is based on "Normal" but has the font set to a monospace font such as Courier New or Consolas.

Then, you can assign a shortcut key to that style. To do that, go into the Style settings and choose "Shortcut Key" from the "Format" dropdown menu in the bottom left corner.